# Getting multiple flutter apps in the same project

Tags: flutter

I've done some searching online for an answer to this but came up empty handed. Is there a way to combine multiple apps in the same flutter project, so they can share parts of the project (theme, widgets, etc)? Think of Uber - where they have two apps - one for the driver and one for the user, but they need to share some common elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach for Uber and similar apps is to have a common database that two apps are communicating with, but each app is a separate codebase. They also probably share libraries, so if you create a library of widgets that define the style or common features for your app you can easily copy/paste that library into multiple projects.

Comment: Nice, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you.